# Boost Python Hello World example not working in Python, AGAIN

Tags: python, boost, dll, boost-python, pythonpath

I have the same problem than the guy here

[Boost Python Hello World example not working in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11036319/boost-python-hello-world-example-not-working-in-python)

who solved his problem, without indicating how. The posts there being quite old, after having posted there also, I create now a new question here, for refreshing things a bit. So... :

My configuration : **windows 8 62bits**, python 2.7.3 32 bits, visual studio 2010 ultimate

I followed

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/html/python/exposing.html

I have created a win32application project called CLIB in visual studio, and ticked "dll" but not "export symbols".

In VC++ directories in properties I put :

C:\Python27x86\include;C:\boost\boost_1_53_0;$(IncludePath)

for include directories and

C:\boost\boost_1_53_0\stage\lib;C:\Python27x86\libs;$(LibraryPath)

for library directories.

In CLIB.cpp I put

```
// CLIB.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/python.hpp>

using namespace boost::python;

struct World
{
    void set(std::string msg) { this->msg = msg; }
    std::string greet() { return msg; }
    std::string msg;
};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
{
    boost::python::class_<World>("World")
        .def("greet", &World::greet)
        .def("set", &World::set)
        ;
}
```

I tried with or without adding

```
#define BOOST_PYTHON_STATIC_LIB
```

Then I compiled in debug mode (with success), the output .dll (or .pyd, I have tried both without any success by modifying the target extension from .dll to .pyd in "general" in "configuration properties" of the project) CLIB.dll is in a directory whose path I added to the PYTHONPATH also. I have even tried to put a blank **init**.py in the same directory than the dll, and, whatever I do, I am not able to do a

```
import hello
```

in the python script (created from fresh either with notepad++ or with pyscripter 32 bits). So if someone could give precise help, that would be perfect.

Thx a lot.

////////////////////////// EDIT 1 ///////////////////////////

In the meantime I saw python 2.7 was compiled with mvs2008, so erase everything, installed python 3.3, rebuilt boost and boost.python with python 3.3, and retried, but... same result...

////////////////////////// EDIT 2 ///////////////////////////

As suggested a run the python script with the very verbose -vv command, here is the result :

```
PS C:\Users\TheUser\Desktop\CLIB\Release> python -vv .\script.py
import _frozen_importlib # frozen
import imp # builtin
import sys # builtin
# installing zipimport hook
import 'zipimport' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# installed zipimport hook
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\__init__.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-33.pyc
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\codecs.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\codecs.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\codecs.cpython-33.pyc
import '_codecs' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'codecs' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01E50870>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\aliases.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\aliases.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\aliases.cpython-33.pyc
import 'encodings.aliases' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01E91B90>
import 'encodings' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01E503F0>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\mbcs.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\mbcs.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\mbcs.cpython-33.pyc
import 'encodings.mbcs' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01E9E730>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\utf_8.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\utf_8.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\utf_8.cpython-33.pyc
import 'encodings.utf_8' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01E9E8D0>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\latin_1.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\latin_1.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\latin_1.cpython-33.pyc
import 'encodings.latin_1' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01E9E9B0>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\io.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\io.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\io.cpython-33.pyc
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\abc.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\abc.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\abc.cpython-33.pyc
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\_weakrefset.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\_weakrefset.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\_weakrefset.cpython-33.pyc
import '_weakrefset' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01EA7150>
import 'abc' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01E9EC30>
import 'io' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01E9EB10>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\cp850.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\cp850.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\cp850.cpython-33.pyc
import 'encodings.cp850' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01EA7F50>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\site.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\site.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\site.cpython-33.pyc
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\os.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\os.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\os.cpython-33.pyc
import 'errno' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\stat.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\stat.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\stat.cpython-33.pyc
import 'stat' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01EBD190>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\ntpath.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\ntpath.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\ntpath.cpython-33.pyc
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\genericpath.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\genericpath.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\genericpath.cpython-33.pyc
import 'genericpath' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01EBDE50>
import 'ntpath' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01EBDAD0>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\collections\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\collections\__init__.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\collections\__pycache__\__init__.cpython-33.pyc
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\collections\__pycache__\abc.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\collections\abc.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\collections\__pycache__\abc.cpython-33.pyc
import 'collections.abc' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x027C3FB0>
import '_collections' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'operator' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\keyword.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\keyword.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\keyword.cpython-33.pyc
import 'keyword' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x027E1330>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\heapq.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\heapq.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\heapq.cpython-33.pyc
import 'itertools' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\bisect.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\bisect.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\bisect.cpython-33.pyc
import '_bisect' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'bisect' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x027E1EF0>
import '_heapq' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'heapq' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x027E1910>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\weakref.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\weakref.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\weakref.cpython-33.pyc
import 'weakref' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x027E1950>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\reprlib.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\reprlib.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\reprlib.cpython-33.pyc
import 'reprlib' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x027E9CF0>
import 'collections' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01EC0CD0>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\copyreg.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\copyreg.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\copyreg.cpython-33.pyc
import 'copyreg' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x027EFD10>
import 'os' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01EB3130>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\re.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\re.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\re.cpython-33.pyc
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\sre_compile.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\sre_compile.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\sre_compile.cpython-33.pyc
import '_sre' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\sre_parse.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\sre_parse.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\sre_parse.cpython-33.pyc
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\sre_constants.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\sre_constants.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\sre_constants.cpython-33.pyc
import 'sre_constants' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x028054F0>
import 'sre_parse' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x027FD530>
import 'sre_compile' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01EB3690>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\functools.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\functools.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\functools.cpython-33.pyc
import '_functools' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'functools' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x027FD8D0>
import 're' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01EBD5D0>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\sysconfig.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\sysconfig.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\sysconfig.cpython-33.pyc
import 'sysconfig' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0280D9F0>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\locale.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\locale.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\__pycache__\locale.cpython-33.pyc
import '_locale' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
import 'locale' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x0281B810>
# C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\cp1252.cpython-33.pyc matches C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py
# code object from C:\Python33x86\Lib\encodings\__pycache__\cp1252.cpython-33.pyc
import 'encodings.cp1252' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x02825350>
import 'site' # <_frozen_importlib.SourceFileLoader object at 0x01EA4290>
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:55:48) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
import 'math' # <class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\script.py", line 2, in <module>
    import CLIB
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1558, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1525, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 586, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 497, in set_package_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 510, in set_loader_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1130, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 313, in _call_with_frames_removed
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: Please run the code in the local directory of your module. What exact error message do you get? Just "module not found" or something more specific?

Comment: Tried what you said, same error : just "Import Error : no module named 'hello'". In the meantime I saw python 2.7 was compiled with mvs2008, so erase everything, installed python 3.3, rebuilt boost and boost.python with python 3.3, and retried, but... same result... What do you think ?

Comment: As noted in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15576882/1053968) answer, consider running python with [`-vv`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-trace-v) arguments.  This should provide insight into what is attempted with `import`.

Comment: I put the result of the operation in the edit of my initial question... I don't know if it is really helpful...

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a difference between the the import statement(s), the extension module name, and the extension library name:

The [`BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/python/doc/v2/module.html#BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE-spec) macro defines the module initializer function.  In `CLIB.cpp` change

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
```

to

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(CLIB)
```

Next, verify that the resulting output library has a CLIB prefix.  Python3.3 removed support for some of the rarely used module name variants.  Per the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/windows.html#is-a-pyd-file-the-same-as-a-dll), I would suggest trying a `.pyd` file extension first, and resorting to `.dll` if the `.pyd` does not work.  Thus, the resulting library should be `CLIB.pyd`.

Finally, when trying to import the extension use

```
import CLIB
```

instead of

```
import hello
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, in the mean time change the "hello" from

    BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(hello)
    {
        //...
    }

to CLIB, and I'm compiling in release mode, a pyd file called CLIB.pyd, in a directory where I put my python script in which I did also a "import CLIB", without any success. Hum, I'm getting mad. ;-) I don't remember where on stack I saw someone saying, about boost.python, something like : "duh, forget about it, its code is rotting on the vine"...

Comment: @MisesEnForce: If renaming the file to `CLIB.dll` does not work, then you may want to consider reverting back to 2.7.3 for the more meaningful verbosity of imports when running with `-vv`.

Comment: Hum, should I stay with MVS2010 then ? Should I recompile boost and boost.python with mvsc-9.0 (and python 2.7.3) also ? Because I did all of this before switching to 3.3, especially because I wanted to used mvs2010, and because I read that 2.7. shoud not be used with mvs2010 for compiling boost.python ? Thx